# Exposing the vulnerability of CTR mode of operation

Tags: aes, stream-cipher, initialization-vector, ctr, nonce

In the CTR mode of operation, the plaintext block is treated as a stream cipher, where each byte of the plaintext gets XOR-ed with each byte of the key (which is generated using a nonce and a counter) to form the ciphertext. This was a part of a challenge that I came across recently. Suppose I have a nonce of 8 bytes that is generated randomly and a counter of 8 bytes, that starts from the value 0 and gets incremented by 10 each time. Now, we have a server which takes input from the user. It returns the input back as output, but in encoded form, except one time. If the input is "!msg", it returns back the variable **MSG**, which is to be recovered. Here's the server code implementation that was given-

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

MSG = "REMOVED"

key = get_random_bytes(AES.block_size)
nonce = get_random_bytes(AES.block_size//2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctr_val = 0
    print("Welcome to the Server!")
    print("Input \"!msg\" to have the message sent to you.")

    while True:
        inp = input("\n$ ")
        outp = None
        if inp == "!msg":
            outp = MSG
        else:
            outp = inp
        
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce=nonce, initial_value=ctr_val); ctr_val += 10
        inp_enc = cipher.encrypt(inp.encode()).hex()


        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce=nonce, initial_value=ctr_val); ctr_val += 10
        outp_enc = cipher.encrypt(outp.encode()).hex()


        print(f"Encrypted Input (hex): {inp_enc}")
        print(f"Encrypted Output (hex): {outp_enc}")
```

When we connect to the server and send the input as "!msg", it returns back the input's (which is "!msg) encrypted form and the output's encrypted form (which is the content of the variable MSG) (in hexadecimal). I suspect that this exposes the CTR mode to certain attacks, as the same nonce is being used to encrypt two different blocks when the input is "!msg", but I don't know how to exploit this vulnerability to get back the MSG. Can someone help me with a clue? I'm new to cryptography and I'm willing to learn on the go.

Comment: Yeah, but the nonce is only getting repeated, the keystream can still be different, right? The nonce and counter together are sent to the AES block, which is a PRG, so it can produce a completely different key notwithstanding the fact that we used the same nonce twice.

Comment: The server performs double encryption using a counter offset. Think about what happens to large messages, note that the cipher will increase the counter block by 1 internally, and that encryption = decryption. At least I think that is the clue, this seems to be a pretty weird assignment.

Comment: So, the counter value starts from 0 and if it's a long enough sentence, it'll reach 10 and move on. Now, the same plaintext is encrypted with the same nonce but now, the counter starts from 10. So, we'd be having the same nonce+counter for the plaintext from the first instance from the 10th byte as the second instance. The key remains the same for both. If we pass the same nonce+counter to the AES scheme with same key for the same plaintext twice, do we get the same output in both the cases? Isn't AES a PRG?

Comment: AES is a block cipher which is a keyed permutation, CTR is a PRG but **pseudo** random means that it does generate the same output if the IV or counter value is repeated for the same key.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have a follow-up question. I took 640 bytes of a string containing only 0's, the server sent the encrypted input and output, input and output both being the same. Next, I sent the string that sends me back MSG. So, the last part of the encrypted input from my first instance would have counter same as the encrypted MSG that I would get as my output. The keys are the same, so a XOR between the 2 ciphertexts would mean a XOR between the two plaintexts. One of the plaintexts is filled with 0's, so XOR b/w the MSG and it would be the MSG itself! But it didn't work.

Comment: Instead, when I just took some random plaintext and took the XOR between the ciphertexts and another XOR between this known plaintext and the XOR between the two ciphertexts, I got back my MSG. Why is this so? Why did it not work when I took a string filled with 0's? Shouldn't a XOR bw MSG and a string of 0's give back the MSG only?

Comment: Must be some error during testing, can't think of anything different. Nice that you were able to get it solved though.